# Java apache tika - Extracting footer of word document

Tags: java, apache-tika, extract, doc

I'm trying to extract the whole content of a word document. I was able to extract it's metadata and the content itself but somehow the text in the footer isn't being extracted.
I would highly appreciate your help. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using, and how are you calling Tika?

Comment: Please provide your code or commands run to extract data.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off using Apache POI - for example: [Read MS Word DOCX Header, Footer, Paragraph and Table Example](https://www.concretepage.com/apache-api/apache-poi-xwpf-read-ms-word-docx-header-footer-paragraph-table-example)